# Why does Iphone not display attachments sent by python 2.7.x

Tags: python, ios, attachment, smtplib

Dear fellow developers

I have a problem where attachments sent by Python 2.7.5 **smtplib** combined with **MIMEBase** are discarded/not displayed by the email client on iOS for iPad and iPhones (but are received and shown on all other platforms).

I'm using program code straight from the python docs site example.

```
msgOther = MIMEBase(mimeMainType, mimeSubType)
msgOther.set_payload(binData)
encoders.encode_base64(msgOther)
msgOther.add_header(u'Content-Disposition', u'attachment', filename=binDisplayName)
MessageData.attach(msgOther)
```

where **binData** is a .pdf file generated by Qt4
and **mimeMainType** = application,
and **mimeSubType** = pdf,
and **binDisplayName** = BaseNameOfFileWithoutPath

Email sent by code above is **received fine and well** on:
Microsoft Windows XP/7/8 with Outlook express and Exchange.
Thunderbird on Linux desktop,
GMail Webmail,
GMail POP3 client on Android mobile,
Standard email client in Samsung mobile devices,
Mac OSX Desktop standard mail client.

HOWEVER on iPhone and iPad devices, the attachments are not shown.
Only the main (HTML)body and inline images I send are shown but a **.pdf** or a **.docx** as attachment are not shown at all.

The main body part is set to **alternative** or **mixed** (I tried both but without result). I also tried multiple or single attachements without result where this works always all the time fine on the other platforms.

Does somebody else has the same experience?

Note:I'm running Python 2.7.5 on Fedora Linux 20.

Comment: I'm having this exact problem and, as noted in the original post, alternative or mixed does not provide the fix. iPads show a paperclip icon indicating the attachment is sent, but there's no other indication or ability to access it.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('alternative')
```

Use:

```
msg = MIMEMultipart('mixed')
```